# Rails routing to external site from model column through controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having an issue in my controller. I'm making url objects with original_url short_url and sanitized_url. I can create and save the links just fine. The issue i'm having is when following the short link back to mysite.com/short_url  it needs to go through the controller show and grab the sanitized url and redirect to that external site.
Can someone help me figure out what's wrong with this code?

I'm getting undefined method 'sanitized_url'

urls_controller.rb - show

```
short = params[:short_url]
@url = Url.where("short_url = ? ", short)

redirect_to @url.sanitized_url
```

My routes.

```
  root to: 'urls#index'
  get "/:short_url", to: "urls#show"
  get "shortened/:short_url", to: "urls#shortened", as: :shortened
  resources :urls
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> undefined method 'sanitized_url'

`where` returns *AR collection*. You need to apply `sanitized_url` on an instance

Below should work

```
short = params[:short_url]
@url = Url.where("short_url = ? ", short).first

redirect_to @url.sanitized_url
```

Comment: When I run the code in the console it grabs the saved url just fine, but it seams to be a routing issue because when you follow the link back to the site. It doesn't recognize its a short url. I have a demo ap link if you want to get a better example. https://retrospect-jr.herokuapp.com/urls

Comment: @Jrinard Can't understand what you are telling. Did my answer resolved the issue?

Comment: Yes it did resolve it. I'm realizing I had an issue in my routes. When I move the resources :urls above the custom routes it fixed it. Thanks for your help! I +1 but my rep is still too low to show. Thanks